# Dell XPS 13 Crashing on Factory Reset (CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED)

Tags: windows-10, crash, reset

Im trying to factory reset on my Dell XPS 13 however everytime I choose any option in the 'Reset My PC' menu, it loads, restarts my laptop and then crashes with the blue screen containing error code: CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED.

How do I resolve this? I've owned my XPS for 3 years and there have been no problems with SSD corruption or any hardware failures so I'm assuming is a Windows 10 (my current OS) problem. I've tried researching a solution however they're mainly just alternative was to factory reset to all of which have failed

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Is there some reason you're doing a factory reset, or just wanting a clean slate?

Comment: Just passing the laptop on, and it seems over time junk has built up in the C drive so just wanted to factory reset to have it as I first bought it as well as removing my data

Comment: there should be a Dell factory recovery partition than can be accessed during bios post (F8?), do a factory reset using that Dell utility instead of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xef--critical-process-died

These general troubleshooting tips may be helpful.

If you recently added hardware to the system, try removing or replacing it. Or check with the manufacturer to see if any patches are available.

If new device drivers or system services have been added recently, try removing or updating them. Try to determine what changed in the system that caused the new bug check code to appear.

Check the System Log in Event Viewer for additional error messages that might help pinpoint the device or driver that is causing the error. For more information, see Open Event Viewer. Look for critical errors in the system log that occurred in the same time window as the blue screen.

Check with the manufacturer to see if an updated system BIOS or firmware is available.

You can try running the hardware diagnostics supplied by the system manufacturer.

Confirm that any new hardware that is installed is compatible with the installed version of Windows. For example, you can get information about required hardware at Windows 10 Specifications.

Run a virus detection program. Viruses can infect all types of hard disks formatted for Windows, and resulting disk corruption can generate system bug check codes. Make sure the virus detection program checks the Master Boot Record for infections.

Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files. The System File Checker is a utility in Windows that allows users to scan for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files. Use the following command to run the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe).

SFC /scannow

For more information, see Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files.

Look in Device Manager to see if any devices are marked with the exclamation point (!). Review the events log displayed in driver properties for any faulting driver. Try updating the related driver.